# Shopify polaris (React js) button click event is not working

Tags: laravel, reactjs, button, onclicklistener, shopify-app

I am newbie to react js.
After couple of hours finally I have some login box code rendering.

But the issue is I am unable to bind click event on button.
What i am using.

1. Laravel 5.6
2. react js (16.3.1)

What i have tried until now is

1. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_events.htm
2. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

This is my final code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Page, Card, Button,List,TextField} from '@shopify/polaris';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor() {

        super();
        this.loginBtbClicked = this.loginBtbClicked.bind(this);
}
loginBtbClicked() {
      debugger;
      console.log('Hello');
}
render() {
    debugger;
    /* Some css code has been removed for brevity */
    var divStyle = {
        width: '500px'
    };
    return (
        <div className="mt-5 mx-auto" style={ divStyle }>
        <Card title="Login" subdued sectioned>
            <div>
            <TextField label="Store Url" type="text" helpText='ex. store.myshopify.com'></TextField>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-5">
            <Button  size="large" fullWidth primary onClick = {this.loginBtbClicked} >Login</Button>
            </div>
        </Card>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Also help me with best practice in react js for form submit and click event.

Here is the link for github project

https://github.com/little-isaac/shopify-polaris-laravel-test.git

Comment: Could you prepare some test project that demonstrates it? Everything seems fine with code you shared.

Comment: Yeah sure give me couple of minutes i will share github link.

Comment: I have update link to question 

1. My Login component goes under the 

resources/assets/js/components/Login.js

Hope it will help.
@TomaszMularczyk

Comment: Ohhh man What i feel is  i have changed path for webpack.mix.js
That is what making issue with js.
It is always using older path to generate new js and...render  older js with new path.

Comment: I don't know how to run it. Your code looks fine there must be something else.

Comment: Yeah i have made it working Don't worry.
Any ways Thanks @TomaszMularczyk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed webpack.mix.js file's path

From

```
mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/app.js')
```

to

```
mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'js/app.js')
```

And forget to change public path

```
mix.setPublicPath('');
```